# Google Cloud API Key permissions

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-error-reporting

I'm using Google's API Key on one of the projects I'm running in the cloud.
I tried to find the permissions that API Key has: does it have write-only? 
Or other types of permissions like read?

I couldn't find anything in Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=en-GB) to prove this, beyond the restrictions I could put on the key, such as restricting HTTP or the API that only the developer could work with.